# How do I assign each charactor to a variable after mb_strlen

Tags: php, foreach, strlen

Once I have countedt the string legnth

```
$total = $_POST['password'];

$count = mb_strlen( $total );
```

I want to do something like a `foreach` loop and assign each charactor to a variable which can be accessed later and manipulated.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [str_split](http://php.net/str_split), without the second ( `split_length` ) argument each value will be one character in length.

```
foreach( str_split( "0123456789" ) as $value ) {
    print_r( $value );
}
```

Comment: why not just `foreach(array("0123456789") as $value){..`.

Comment: @Dagon, that array has only one element "0123456789", asker wants to split string into array of characters

Answer (score 0):

you can access any string in an array fashion

```
$str="abcdefg";

echo $str[2]; //c
```

Comment: But i want all of the charactors in the form submitted. How do i count the ammount of charactors and assign only that number to variables. it could be 10 or it could be 100.

Comment: sorry, no idea what you are asking